# Может ли слово быть ориентиром в регулярном выражении Java?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Приведу пример:

```
String string1 = "Owner=John Pet=Dog City=NY";
String string2 = "Owner=Steve Pet=Cat City=LA";
String string3= "Owner=Paul Pet=Hamster City=LS";

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add(string1);
strings.add(string2);
strings.add(string3);
```

Могу ли я как-то (с помощью регулярного выражения), вытащить все типы животных опираясь на ключевое слово "Pet"? Если нет, то какой подход лучше использовать в регулярке?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для варианта с названием из нескольких слов

```
(?<=Pet=)[\w ]+(?<![ City])
```

В Java будет:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=Pet=)[\w ]+(?<![ City])").matcher(str);
if (m.find()){
    String pet = m.group();
}
```

Но надежней и быстрее в общем случае будет спарсить всю строку, а значения взять из групп.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("Owner=(.*) Pet=(.*) City=(.*)").matcher(str);
if (m.find()){
    String owner = m.group(1);
    String pet = m.group(2);
    String city = m.group(3);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Pet=(\w+)
```

Первая группа вернет Dog, Cat, Hamster  и тд

Answer (score 2):

[Вариант](https://regex101.com/r/b4zGiX/1) с позитивным просмотром назад:

```
(?<=Pet=)\w+
```

Comment: Это выражение нужно передавать в параметр Pattern.compile()?